# Android admob xml issue

Tags: android, admob

I have a simple problem with admob here...

I've tried all resources to add admob on my android app
but somehow, when i try to add this code to the layout xml:

```
<Linearlayout
       ......./>

       <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
         myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
       myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
       />
```

it says, *The prefix "myapp" for attribute "myapp:backgroundColor" associated with an element type "com.admob.android.ads.AdView" is not bound*

what's wrong?

I've add the attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
<declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">
    <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="keywords" format="string" />
    <attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
       </resources>
```

and also the xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.suit.AdmobTest" in my manifest...

THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the `myapp` namespace to the root element of your layout file. In you case to the LinearLayout element. The element then has to namespace references. The standard Android reference `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` and your myapp reference `xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.suit.AdmobTest"`.

This should do the job.

Comment: Hey! great work so far.... now, by the tutorial I supposed to call AdManager function from the jar to make a test ads...., from the sdk that i've downloaded, there's no such class on it... I'm wondering if i downloaded wrong package....

Comment: now why it says "class ads.android.admob.AdView not found" wtf?